# How can a set of N players be split into M teams, given certain rules?

Tags: sets

A lot of times, I’ve needed to split a given set of people into a given number of teams but with some complications, like:

- Alice and Bob CANNOT be on the same team.
- Carol and David just HAVE TO BE on the same team.

I feel like this is already a thing. There's gotta already be work in this problem. Where would I even start, in terms of an algorithm? It definitely can't be brute-forced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote each person as a single vertex and connect them by an edge if they are not allowed to be in the same team. If several people have to be on the same team, use a single vertex to represent all of them. Then color the resulting graph by $k$ colors, where $k$ is the number of teams.This problem is the graph coloring problem. To complicate things you may require color certain vertices in the same color. Please follow [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) for other types of colorings.